# Bootstrap navbar-collapse that collapses into three columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, grid-layout

I am developing a website using Undestrap-child theme in Wordpress.

I have a navbar that always collapse with 100% height, but the nav-links appear one under the other, all centered.

What I want: When collapsed, I would like my nav-links to be shown in three columns at min-width:768px.

here's my nav:

```js
<!-- ******************* The Navbar Area ******************* -->
<div id="wrapper-navbar">

  <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable"
     href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'understrap' ); ?></a>

  <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent"
       aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">

    <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
      <?php esc_html_e( 'Main Navigation', 'understrap' ); ?>
    </h2>

    <?php if ( 'container' === $container ) : ?>
    <div class="container">
      <?php endif; ?>

      <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->
      <?php if ( ! has_custom_logo() ) { ?>

      <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>

      <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0"><a rel="home"
         href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
         title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
         itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
      </h1>

      <?php else : ?>

      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home"
         href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
         title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>"
         itemprop="url"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>

      <?php endif; ?>

      <?php
                        } else {
                            the_custom_logo();
                        }
                        ?>
      <!-- end custom logo -->

      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
        aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle navigation', 'understrap' ); ?>">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
      <?php
                    wp_nav_menu(
                        array(
                            'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id' => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                'menu_class' => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                'fallback_cb' => '',
                'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
                'depth' => 2,
                'walker' => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
              )
           ); ?>
      <?php if ( 'container' === $container ) : ?>
    </div><!-- .container -->
    <?php endif; ?>

  </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->

</div><!-- #wrapper-navbar end -->
```

and how it appears from the browser:

```js
<div id="wrapper-navbar">

  <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Salta al
    contenuto</a>

  <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent"
       aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">

    <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
      Main Navigation </h2>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->


      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="http://localhost:3000/"
         title="zb_collezioni" itemprop="url">zb_collezioni</a>


      <!-- end custom logo -->

      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button"
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
              aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="true"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
      <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse show"
           style="">
        <ul id="main-menu"
            class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-lg-fill text-lg-center">
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-157"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul"
               href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-158"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-158 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/"
               class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-160"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-160 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/"
               class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-161"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul"
               href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-162"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-162 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/"
               class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-163"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul"
               href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-164"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-164 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/"
               class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-165"
              class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul"
               href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope"
              itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement"
              id="menu-item-169"
              class="rights menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169 nav-item">
            <a title="All rights reserved" href="#" class="nav-link">All rights
              reserved</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .container -->

  </nav><!-- .site-navigation -->
</div>
```

Is there a way, maybe using Bootstrap classes, to achieve what I have in mind?

Thank you for your help!

A working snippet:

```css
#wrapper-navbar {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-navbar">

  <a class="skip-link sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#content">Salta al
    contenuto</a>

  <nav id="main-nav" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-transparent" aria-labelledby="main-nav-label">

    <h2 id="main-nav-label" class="sr-only">
      Main Navigation </h2>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Your site title as branding in the menu -->


      <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="http://localhost:3000/" title="zb_collezioni" itemprop="url">zb_collezioni</a>


      <!-- end custom logo -->

      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
      <div id="navbarNavDropdown" class="navbar-collapse collapse show" style="">
        <ul id="main-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-lg-fill text-lg-center">
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-157" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-157 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul" href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-158" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-158 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-160" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-160 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-161" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-161 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul" href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-162" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-162 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-163" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-163 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul" href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-164" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-131 current_page_item active menu-item-164 nav-item">
            <a title="I Colori" href="http://localhost:3000/i-colori/" class="nav-link" aria-current="page">I Colori</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165 nav-item">
            <a title="Authentic Soul" href="http://localhost:3000/authentic-soul/" class="nav-link">Authentic
              Soul</a></li>
          <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-169" class="rights menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-169 nav-item">
            <a title="All rights reserved" href="#" class="nav-link">All rights
              reserved</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .container -->

  </nav>
  <!-- .site-navigation -->
</div>

<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the navbar HTML from the browser? It's hard to read the posted markup with all the PHP, and the PHP is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: @terrymorse you're absolutely right! I've updated the question with the HTML from the browser, thank you for your suggestion!